# Routing phone microphone to Sco Bluetooth headset in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, audio-streaming, headset

How those chances upon my posts throw the last year saw how much I struggled with this application.
Now I have reached to the final phase and I really cannot understand why the code doesn't work. What I'm trying to do is to route the audio stream from the phone microphone to a sco Bluetooth headset.
The Phone is Samsung Galaxy s2 and the headset is Esco Plastronics. 
I followed the documentation on android web site and this is what I have done so far:

```
tools.Log("&&&&&&&& debug &&&&&&&&&","");
tools.Log("&&&&&&&& debug &&&&&&&&&","");
tools.Log("&&&&&&&& debug &&&&&&&&&","");
tools.Log("FBR.SetUpAudioRecoder", "In");
public static final int SAMPPERSER =  8000;
public int channelConfiguration = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
public int audioEncoding = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
public AudioManager AM = (AudioManager) mcontext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

buffersizebytes = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(SAMPPERSEC,channelConfiguration, audioEncoding);     buffersizebytes = (short) (buffersizebytes * 20);
audioRecord = new AudioRecord(
      android.media.MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,SAMPPERSEC,channelConfiguration,audioEncoding,buffersizeb   ytes); // constructor
//Debug
boolean tmp = AM.isBluetoothScoAvailableOffCall();//Returns true
tools.Log("AM.isBluetoothScoAvailableOffCall() is -",tools.BoolToString(tmp));
try {
    audioRecord.startRecording();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    tools.Log("FBR.GetAudioFromMic:startRecording:Error ",
                e.getMessage());
    return "Get Audio From Mic Error";
}
AM.setStreamSolo(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, true);
AM.setBluetoothScoOn(true);
AM.startBluetoothSco();// HERE I GET A BEEP ON THE HEADSET
tmp = AM.isBluetoothScoOn();// Returns true
tools.Log("AM.isBluetoothScoOn() is - ",    tools.BoolToString(tmp));
tools.Log("&&&&&&&& end debug &&&&&&&&&","");
tools.Log("&&&&&&&& end debug &&&&&&&&&","");
tools.Log("&&&&&&&& end debug &&&&&&&&&","");
```

The permitions on the manifest file are:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY"/>
```

The log gives me a lot of information which I cannot understand so I just attached few lines.

```
20 08:56:02.090:D/SpySitter(9659): &&&&&&&&& debug &&&&&&&&&&-
01-20 08:56:02.090: D/SpySitter(9659): FBR.SetUpAudioRecoder-In

01-20 08:56:02.100: I/AudioHardwareYamaha(1833): getInputBufferSize() rate 8000, size 512 

01-20 08:56:02.110: I/AudioPolicyManager(1833): getDeviceForInputSource()input source 1, device 00100000

01-20 08:56:02.110: I/AudioHardwareYamaha(1833): AudioStreamIn::set(1, 16, 8000)

01-20 08:56:02.110: I/AudioHardwareYamaha(1833): bufferSize() channels 2, bufferRatio 4, size 1024

01-20 08:56:02.115: I/AudioHardwareYamaha(1833): AudioStreamIn::standby()

01-20 08:56:02.120: D/SpySitter(9659): AM.isBluetoothScoAvailableOffCall() is - -true

01-20 08:56:02.125: I/AudioService(1989): isMediaSilentMode false

20 08:56:02.140: I/AudioPolicyManager(1833): getDeviceForStrategy() strategy 4, device 2

01-20 08:56:02.145: I/AudioPolicyManager(1833): setForceUse() usage 2, config 3, mPhoneState 0

01-20 08:56:03.475: E/DataRouter(1828): usb connection is true 

01-20 08:56:03.475: E/DataRouter(1828): DSR is ON. Don't send DTR ON

01-20 08:56:05.010: D/Bluetooth HS/HF(2240): initiateScoUsingVirtualVoiceCall: Received

01-20 08:56:05.010: V/Bluetooth AT sent(2240): +CIEV: 3,2

01-20 08:56:05.010: D/Bluetooth HS/HF(2240): initiateScoUsingVirtualVoiceCall: Sent Call-setup 
procedure

01-20 08:56:05.010: D/Bluetooth HS/HF(2240): audioOn()

01-20 08:56:05.010: D/Bluetooth HS/HF(2240): setAudioState(11)

01-20 08:56:05.015: D/Bluetooth HSHFP(2240): AudioStateIntent:  State: 11 PrevState: 10

01-20 08:56:05.015: V/BluetoothSocket.cpp(2240): initSocketNative

01-20 08:56:05.015: V/BluetoothSocket.cpp(2240): ...fd 99 created (SCO, lm = 0)

01-20 08:56:05.015: V/BluetoothSocket.cpp(2240): initSocketFromFdNative

01-20 08:56:05.040: D/Bluetooth HS/HF(2240): initiateScoUsingVirtualVoiceCall: Done

01-20 08:56:05.045: I/BluetoothPolicyService(1989): isPairingEnabled 

01-20 08:56:05.055: D/BluetoothUtils(2240): isSocketAllowedBySecurityPolicy start : device null

01-20 08:56:05.055: V/BluetoothSocket.cpp(2240): connectNative

01-20 08:56:05.065: V/Bluetooth AT recv(2240): AT+CLCC

01-20 08:56:05.070: V/Bluetooth AT sent(2240): +CLCC: 1,0

01-20 08:56:05.080: V/BluetoothSocket.cpp(2240): ...connect(99, SCO) = 0 (errno 115)

01-20 08:56:05.080: D/Bluetooth HS/HF(2240): Routing audio for outgoing SCO conection

01-20 08:56:16.455: D/SpySitter(9659): &&&&&&&&&&&& end debug&&&&&&&&
```

alot of thanks for helping

Comment: @c v, did you manage to solve the problem? I am facing the same problem, the recorded file contains just silence, it seems it is trying to get hold of the Bluetooth microphone but couldn't reach it. I am surprised it didn't route to the Phone microphone in case if it didn't get hold of the Bluetooth microphone.

Comment: By using AM.setBluetoothSco(true) the device route the audio to and from bluetooth headset .

Comment: @Harish Never got this working on android above 4.0( Ice ream sandwich)

Answer (score 2):

Right around AM.setBluetoothScoOn(true), you may need to call AM.setMode(MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);

Comment: but this is not working in android lollipop.any workaround for that?